# Finding the maximum of a function in c++

Tags: c++, max

I am having a great deal of difficulty even figuring out where to start with this one. I need to create a program that finds the maximum of a function f(x) over an interval, a less than or equal to x less than or equal to b, starting at x=a with a step size of delta x. I'm supposed to do more with the program, but first I really need to just get the basics listed above coded. I honestly have no idea of how to go about doing so and it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like a looping construct is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In general,

```
// initial value for this should be less than any value of f(x)
float max_fx = NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

// this syntax
// for (initialization statment; continuation test; change of state)
// does the {...} block some number of times until the continuation test fails
// and does the change of state after each run through
for (float x = a; x <= b; x = x + delta)
{
    // first time the loop runs, x will equal a
    // next time, x will equal a + delta
    // then a + delta + delta
    // etc

    // compute the value
    const float fx = f (x);

    if (fx > max_fx) // note any fx will be greater than NEGATIVE_INFINITY
        max_fx = fx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the function, you can get the derivative then equate it to zero. Then solve it to get its maximum point.

Example:

```
      f(x)=pow(x,2) + 2 * x

      derivative is 2*x + 2

      so its maximum can be found by:  

      2*x + 2 = 0 
      x = -2 / 2 ==> -1

      x= -1 point is highest/ lowest part of the function. Then -inf and +inf are other minimum/maximum parts.
```

Or you divide whole area into a million parts and check each one because you can never know where that function will rise/fall after another hill.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the function, just take the derivative and find where it's zero.  Then compare those numbers with f(a) and f(b) to see which is greatest.  That is the absolute maximum on the interval [a,b].

for finding derivatives of polynomials:

d/dx[x^n] = n*x^(n-1) and

d/dx[f(x)+g(x)] = d/dx[f(x)] + d/dx[g(x)] and

d/dx[cf(x)] = c*d/dx[f(x)]

example:

d/dx[3*x^4 - 2.6*x^3 + 0.97*x^1.5 + x - 5*x^0.3 + 2] =

(3*4)*x^(4-1) - (2.6*3)*x^(3-1) + (0.97*1.5)*x^(1.5-1) + 1 - (5*0.3)*x^(0.3-1) + 0 =

12*x^3 - 7.8*x^2 + 1.455*x^0.5 + 1 - 1.5*x^-0.7